# Autolayout of the images in scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I put images in a UIScrollview programmatically. When I run a simulator on an iPhone 8, the width of each image fits perfectly to the screen. But, when I run it on iPhone 8 Plus, the width of images is shorter than that of the screen. I think there is something wrong with the auto layout. What can be a possible reason behind this? I put the following codes in ViewDidLoad.

```
scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 1")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 2")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 3")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 4")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 5")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 6"))]

scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(scrollViewData.count)

var i = 0
for data in scrollViewData {
    let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
    view.imageView.image = data.image
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view)



    i += 1
```

I put the following code separately

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return imageView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't set any constraints for your ```CustomView``` relative to the ScrollView

Comment: What is your scroll view frame?

Comment: so should i just erase 'let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
    view.imageView.image = data.image?' ?

Comment: I have not put the scroll view frame because I thought the imageView constraints would increase the size of the images accordingly.. wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview probably has the wrong frame in viewDidLoad, since the layout was not yet triggered at this point. Try moving the code to viewWillAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews (and make sure its not called more than once) or alternatively add a view.layoutIfNeeded() call before setting the frames.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what do you mean by 'it's not called more than once'?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called only once when the screen loads. viewWillAppear could be called more times (for example if you push another screen over the current one and then dismiss it) and viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called anytime a layout update is triggered.

Comment: you probably only want to add the custom views as subviews of the scroll view once. And set the frames relative to the scrollview if the layout changes (in viewDidLayoutSubviews)

Comment: I am so sorry but I am a real beginner. Could you please give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor , constant: 0).isActive = true
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor , constant: 0).isActive = true
```